# Overlapping map tiles with mapnik's generate_tiles.py script

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, mapnik

I'm trying to **generate map tiles** using [**the mapnik's generate_tiles.py script**](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/generate_tiles.py), but **the resulting tiles are overlapped**.

### Example

The tiles have the following directory structure: `zoom_level/x_coordinate/y_coordinate.png`.

Tiles **3/4/1.png** , **3/4/2.png** and **3/4/3.png** have some **countries shown twice** (for example: Turkey and a part of Italy) like in the following image:
[image: overlapping tiles]

---

### Begin Edit

Here is how the tiles should look at the **same zoom level** as the previous image (zoom level: 3; these tiles were generated using [**MOBAC**](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) with the "*OpenStreetMap Mapnik*" Map source):
[image: OpenStreetMap Mapnik tiles generated with MOBAC]

As you can see, in this case there aren't any tiles with overlapping content (or duplicate, if you prefer). Another strange thing is that **only the tiles from the middle of the map** (3.png and 4.png) **look similar** (cover *approximately* the same area). The other tiles (0.png , 1.png and 2.png) **look totally different and I don't understand why!!!**

**Note:** this is the first time I generate my own tiles so it's very likely that I'm doing a stupid mistake. It might be related to the **projection** I use (see below for the **osm.xml**).

### End Edit

---

I tried setting the `self.m.buffer_size` to `0 (zero)` (like [this page says](http://benmearns.blogspot.com/2010/08/mapnik-label-cut-off-strategies.html); anyway, that's regarding labels, which I don't need) in:

```
def render_tile(self, tile_uri, x, y, z):
    # ...

    render_size = 256
    self.m.resize(render_size, render_size)
    self.m.zoom_to_box(bbox)
    self.m.buffer_size = 128

    # Render image with default Agg renderer
    im = mapnik.Image(render_size, render_size)
    mapnik.render(self.m, im)
    im.save(tile_uri, 'png256')
```

Could it be a **problem with the projection?** Here are the important bits from my **osm.xml** file:

```
<Map bgcolor="#f2efe9" srs="+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84">
```

and

```
<Layer name="countries" status="on" srs="+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84">
```

**Can someone help me? I already spent almost a week searching and documenting myself about this process and I got stuck here.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slippy maps typically use the EPSG 3857 projection (another name for 900913, Google Web Mercator). In your stylesheet, change all occurrences of `+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84` to `+init=epsg:3857` to use the Spherical Mercator projection.